# Real World Peformance of SQL vs Core Data: Need Perspective and Perhaps Specific Fixes

Tags: objective-c, sql, ios, core-data

I have a word game app that accesses a list of words and clues, which is about 100K entries.  The data base is only accessed, never changed.  I built the app using SQL methods and it performs pretty well on iOS 6 but the time to get a new clue from the data base is extremely slow on iOS 5:

- iOS 5, getting one record from the 100K using SQL, takes about 12
  seconds.
- iOS 6, getting one record from the 100K using SQL, takes
  about 700-1000 milliseconds.

Both of these are on 32 GB iPod Touch.

Given this performance, I made a version using Core Data.  My approach gets a random data base entry by first counting the records that fit the query, then chosing one at random.  Code follows.  Everything I read suggested that Core Data would be faster:

- iOS 5, counting records takes around 4 seconds, and retrieving one of
  those records takes about 50 - 1500 millisecs. A total time of about 5 seconds.
- iOS 6, counting records takes a bit over 2 seconds, and retrieving
  one of those records takes about 300-500 millisecs. A total of about 3 seconds.

So Core Data is faster on iOS 5 but slower on iOS 6, compared to SQL.  Either way the performance is too slow as far as I am concerned.  I know the overhead comes from the methods given below (for the Core Data version).  So, two questions:

1. Any general advice about this issue with an eye to understanding it and improving performance?
2. Specifically, what about the Core Data code appended below: have I done something foolish that slows it down?  Or something else I should add to speed it up?  This is my first attempt at Core Data.

Thanks.

```
- (NSArray *) randomClue {

NSManagedObjectContext* context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"A"];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"WL28"
                               inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [self createSearchQuery];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;

NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSString *timeString1 = [formatter stringFromDate:date1];

int resCount = [context countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                       error:&error];

NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];
NSString *timeString2 = [formatter stringFromDate:date2];

int t1 = [timeString1 intValue];
int t2 = [timeString2 intValue];
int d1 = t2-t1;    
NSLog(@"randomClue:");
NSLog(@"    Time to count array entries: %i", d1);

int ranNum = arc4random_uniform(resCount-1);
int ranNum2 = ranNum + 1;

// Now we fetch just one answer object, not a whole database or even a piece of it!

[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:YES];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:nil];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
[fetchRequest setFetchOffset:ranNum2];

NSDate *date3 = [NSDate date];
NSString *timeString3 = [formatter stringFromDate:date3];

self.wl28 = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSDate *date4 = [NSDate date];
NSString *timeString4 = [formatter stringFromDate:date4];

int t3 = [timeString3 intValue];
int t4 = [timeString4 intValue];
int d2 = t4-t3;
NSLog(@"    Time to retrieve one entry: %i", d2);

return self.wl28;
}
```

**EDIT**: createSearchQuery added below

```
- (NSPredicate *)createSearchQuery {

NSMutableArray *pD = [[GameData gameData].curData valueForKey:@"persData"];
NSNumber *currMin = [pD objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *currMax = [pD objectAtIndex:1];
NSNumber *dicNo = [pD objectAtIndex:2];
NSString *dict = nil;

if ([dicNo intValue] == 0) dict = @"TWL";
if ([dicNo intValue] == 1) dict = @"LWL";

NSPredicate *dictPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dict == %@", dict];
NSPredicate *lowNoCPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"noC >= %@", currMin];
NSPredicate *highNoCPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"noC <= %@", currMax];

NSPredicate *query = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray
                      arrayWithObjects:dictPred, lowNoCPred, highNoCPred,nil]];
NSLog(@"%@", query);
return query;
}
```

Comment: If the database is read-only, why are you counting the entries every time?

Comment: There are subsets depending upon user settings, which in turn affect the query.  The biggest subset is about 70K and that's what the performance numbers are based on.  There are not an infinite number of these, so I might pre-calculate these to save some time I suppose.

Comment: It would be easier if you show us `createSearchQuery` method.

Comment: @TomaszZabłocki Thanks for looking at this: I added the code to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding index to your noC and/or dict attributes inside your entity. It might speed up your query time.

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation?  I have seen mentions of indexed Core Data structures, but the word index doesn't appear in the docs for either `NSPredicate` or the Core Data Programming Guide.

Comment: Ok open xcdatamodel in Xcode, switch to grid editor style, then select your entity, then attribute noC or dict. After selecting it on the right side you have Data Model Inspector. There is property Indexed so simply check it. [Wikipedia - about index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29)

Comment: Great call!  That reduced the time to retrieve a single entry to about 50-200 ms on iOS 6.  The time to count the entries is pretty much unchanged.  Any suggestions about speeding that up?  I think I can hard-wire the number of entries at each possible combination of `dict` and `noC` if needed, which would replace that step with a quick look up.

Comment: Another tip: You could use NSFetchedResultsController to query just once and keep it until your application terminates. That way you could just pick random object from fetchedObjects property reducing time to ~0 for both calls.

Comment: Thank you again.  I will look into NSFetechedResultsController, or I can do something similar: the subset of clues pulled from the main data base changes infrequently, when the user changes the settings.  So I can keep it around for quite some time in an array and grab randomly from it.  Thanks for your help! Accepting answer.